# Selecting entries from deeply nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, geojson

I have a very deeply nested dictionary (geojson) which contains shapefiles with features.
One of these features is 'month_num' by which I want to select the data.
The problem is that this dictionary is deeply nested.
The closest thing I came up with is the following:

```
list(filter(lambda country: ['features'][country]['properties']['month_num'] == 2, geojson_countries))
```

But this gives me the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The geojson file looks like this:

[image]

I want to be able to select all entries which have 'month_num' == 2.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Please post text (maybe a snippet) instead of an image.

Comment: `'features'` appears to be a list of dicts. maybe try `list(filter(lambda country: ['features'][0][country]['properties']['month_num'] == 2, geojson_countries))`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ADLMtHT1
This is the JSON file.

Comment: Why the `country` ? It does not appear in the `JSON` file anywhere.

Comment: My bad, I did not use the lambda function correctly. Your code work flawlessly. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get along with

```
dct = your_dict.copy()
dct["features"] = [item for item in dct["features"] 
                   if item["properties"]["month_num"] == 2]
```

Comment: I just found out that your code removes the first layer, the list of dicts. I am attaching the screenshot of the original list and the copy, which is the result of your code, could you please edit you code to match the original?

https://i.imgur.com/eUbBBRW.png

Comment: @DominikNovotný: Got you, changed the answer. Just copy the dict beforehand.